# ActiveX Component Excel Vba MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos, activex, cryptocurrency

I want to get Crypto prices from Binance to excel and log them.
Below code working fine on Windows but on Mac it gives **run-time error 429** "ActiveX Component can't create object"

```
Sub GetData()

Dim objHTTP As Object, strURL As String, HTMLcode As String
Dim arrProperties()
Dim arrPattern(1 To 21) As String
Dim regExp As Object, xPattern As Variant
Dim r As Integer, c As Byte
Dim strResponse As String, intStatus As Integer, strStatus As String

Range("A1:U" & Rows.Count) = ""

arrProperties = Array("symbol", "priceChange", "priceChangePercent", "weightedAvgPrice", "prevClosePrice", _
                      "lastPrice", "lastQty", "bidPrice", "bidQty", "askPrice", "askQty", "openPrice", _
                      "highPrice", "lowPrice", "volume", "quoteVolume", "openTime", "closeTime", _
                      "firstId", "lastId", "count")
                      
Range("A1:U1") = arrProperties
Range("A1:U1").Font.Bold = True
Range("A1:U1").Font.Color = vbRed

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

strURL = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr"

objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
objHTTP.send

If objHTTP.ReadyState = 4 And objHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    HTMLcode = objHTTP.responseText
    
    arrPattern(1) = """symbol"":""(.+?)"",""priceChange"":"
    arrPattern(2) = """priceChange"":""(.+?)"",""priceChangePercent"":"
    arrPattern(3) = """priceChangePercent"":""(.+?)"",""weightedAvgPrice"":"
    arrPattern(4) = """weightedAvgPrice"":""(.+?)"",""prevClosePrice"":"
    arrPattern(5) = """prevClosePrice"":""(.+?)"",""lastPrice"":"
    arrPattern(6) = """lastPrice"":""(.+?)"",""lastQty"":"
    arrPattern(7) = """lastQty"":""(.+?)"",""bidPrice"":"
    arrPattern(8) = """bidPrice"":""(.+?)"",""bidQty"":"
    arrPattern(9) = """bidQty"":""(.+?)"",""askPrice"":"
    arrPattern(10) = """askPrice"":""(.+?)"",""askQty"":"
    arrPattern(11) = """askQty"":""(.+?)"",""openPrice"":"
    arrPattern(12) = """openPrice"":""(.+?)"",""highPrice"":"
    arrPattern(13) = """highPrice"":""(.+?)"",""lowPrice"":"
    arrPattern(14) = """lowPrice"":""(.+?)"",""volume"":"
    arrPattern(15) = """volume"":""(.+?)"",""quoteVolume"":"
    arrPattern(16) = """quoteVolume"":""(.+?)"",""openTime"":"
    arrPattern(17) = """openTime"":(.+?),""closeTime"":"
    arrPattern(18) = """closeTime"":(.+?),""firstId"":"
    arrPattern(19) = """firstId"":(.+?),""lastId"":"
    arrPattern(20) = """lastId"":(.+?),""count"":"
    arrPattern(21) = """count"":(.+?)}"
    
    Set regExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    regExp.ignorecase = True
    regExp.Global = True
        
    For Each xPattern In arrPattern
        regExp.Pattern = xPattern
        r = 1
        c = c + 1
        If regExp.test(HTMLcode) Then
            For Each retVal In regExp.Execute(HTMLcode)
                r = r + 1
                Cells(r, c) = retVal.Submatches(0)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    Columns("A:U").AutoFit
    MsgBox "›˛lem tamam...", vbInformation
Else
    strResponse = Split(objHTTP.responseText, "status"":")(1)
    intStatus = Split(strResponse, "}")(0) + 0
    
    strResponse = Split(objHTTP.responseText, "error"":""")(1)
    strStatus = Split(strResponse, """")(0)
    
    MsgBox "Durum: " & intStatus & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Hata mesaj˝: " & strStatus
End If

Set regExp = Nothing
Set objHTTP = Nothing
Erase arrPattern
```

End Sub

I find some answers with Dictioanry.cls and KeyValuePair.cls but it does not work for me.
Is there any way to correct this Error on VBA

Comment: What happens when you type `createobject msxml2 xmlhttp alternative macintosh` in google?

Comment: Active-X does not exist on the MAC. You'll need to find an alternative.

Comment: The alternative is in the first stackoverflow post when the search term (mentioned in my comment above) is entered in google @RonRosenfeld :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout I had not seen your comment when I posted mine, even though I posted a few minutes later :-(

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: hey no worries :D

Comment: Thanks for answers,@SiddharthRout  i tired some of them but still not working.

Comment: If you have Python installed then openpyxl would be an alternative, I have code that you can use.